# jQuery .load result into the 'calling' div (rather than a specified id)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm putting together a rather simple 'vote' function - the user clicks on a link, the 'action' page adds the vote to the DB & returns the number of votes.  This is what I currently have;

```
<a onClick="vote(#tipID#);return-false;" class="post-add-icon inline-items" id="tipVote"><i class="far fa-heart"></i> #tipVotes#</a>
```

and the JS;

```
<script>
function vote(num){$("#tipVote").load('/assets/a/vote/?vtype=tip&tipID='+num+'');}
</script>
```

This all works fine, with one exception - I have several divs named 'tipVote' on the page (output is dynamic).  Whilst I can alter the div names by adding an id (i.e tipVote999, tipVote232 etc), I have no way of knowing what those ID's will be prior to the output, and of course it would be incredibly 'messy' to duplicate the code for each id.

So, my question is whether either of these is possible;

- Can I somehow restrict the post back to the div that calls it?  I did try (without success);

  ```
  function vote(num) {
     $('this').load('/assets/a/vote/?vtype=tip&tipID=' + num + '');
  }
  ```
- Or, can I somehow send a variable with the onclick event that also shows the div for post back.  In that vein, I also tried (again without success);

```
    function vote(num){
       $("#tipVote' + num+'").load('/assets/a/vote/?vtype=tip&tipID='+num+'');
    }
```

I've done a fair amount of searching, but found nothing - but I feel this must be something that's been covered before.

Help & Advice much appreciated in advance!

Comment: `vote(#tipID#);` should have the parameter wrapped in quotes like  `vote('#tipID#');` and what is `return-false;` in javascript ?

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple divs with the same `id`. That's semantically incorrect. You'll want to use classes for this if that's the route you take.

Comment: Please share a sample of the received HTML from `'/assets/a/vote/?vtype=tip&tipID`

Comment: @Ele <i class="fas fa-heart text-primary"></i><cfoutput>#newcount.tipVotes#</cfoutput></span> - its basically the same, but with an updated count

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam return-false is to prevent a 'normal' click being registered.  I'm no JS/jQuery expect (by any means), but I've always been shown to add that.  Noted on the quotes, though it does work in it's current form and I don't think that relates to the problem I'm having

Comment: @War10ck - I know, and I hadn't realised that would occur until I spotted this problem (my mistake).  Again, I can change that but it doesn't solve the issue I have here

Comment: you may add an data attribute such as `data-id="yourID"` and then in your function you can get it like `var id = $(this).data('id')`

Comment: Try $(this).load instead of $('this').load. Without quotes around the this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you were almost there; the only problem with this was some mis-nested quotes:

```
function vote(num){
   $("#tipVote" + num).load('/assets/a/vote/?vtype=tip&tipID='+num);
}
```

Assuming the div id is something like "tipVote123", calling either `vote(123)` or `vote('123')` will load the data into that div.

Alternatively, you could read the ID from the DOM instead of passing it as a parameter to the vote function, using whatever DOM traversal gets you from the link the user clicked to the specific div you want filled -- but since it looks like you already have the tipID being passed into the function, may as well use that instead of reading the DOM.

Comment: Perfect! That works a charm.  I've been tearing my hair out with this for what seems like ages - can't believe I was so close to it!  I *really* appreciate you answering.

Comment: Looks like I can't award the bounty until tomorrow, but consider it done.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this: (assumes '#tipID#' is a dynamically generated unique id)

```
<div id="div_"+#tipID#>
<a href='#' class="tipVote post-add-icon inline-items" id= #tipID# ><i class="far fa-heart"></i> #tipVotes#</a>
</div>
```

assumes jQuery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tipVote').click(function () {
      var id = $(this).id();

      var jqxhr = $.post( "/assets/a/vote/?vtype=tip&tipID='+id+''", function() {
        //alert( "success" );
        $('#div_'+id).html('<p>Voted</p>');
      })
      .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This looks likened would be a perfect solution, however when I implement & click on it, the console shows the following error;

TypeError: $(...).id is not a function

Comment: To add to my last comment, I am using jQuery and indeed have scripts successfully running before this using similar ($(document)...etc) syntax.  Oddly, if I change 'var id =' to 'var did' (and subsequent 'id' references - i.e $('#div_'+id) becomes $('#div_'+did) - the TypeError error doesn't show, but nothing executes either (console shows nothing)